# ArtifactTransferException Failure to transfer com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.0

Tags: apache, maven, transfer

I receive this error, after searching found suggestion: remove all maven*.lastUpdated from local repository.
So I did it. Nothing happen.
What else can be done?
Thanks.

Comment: You get this error when? What command are you running, what does your pom file look like, is your maven pulling from central or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the similar error while doing the maven project in eclipse. I solved the problem by doing following steps:

1. Right click the project
2. Goto Maven
3. Click the "Update Project"

Answer (score 1):

In Maven First,you need to know below things are working are not.

1. Are you able to open the repository url which is in settings.xml on your browser.
2. Or Check are you able to download the jars from the repository url.
3. Or Right click on your project and click on Maven and click the Update Project.